# How to verify that an Expression is a Member Access lambda

Tags: c#

Inside a function receiving an expression, how can I check if the expression is a member access lambda ?

```
bool F<TSrc, TVal>(TSrc src, Expression<Func<TSrc, TVal>> exp) { 
  bool isMememberAccess = ???
  if (!isMememberAccess) return false;
  ...
  return true;
}
```

so that:

```
var emp = new Employee(); 
var res = F(emp, x => x.FirstName); // returns true;

var org = new Organization();
var res = F(org, x => x.Sales.Manager.FirstName); // returns true;

int i=0; 
var res = F(emp, x => i); // returns false - expression is not a member access
```

I tried to check for `exp.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess` but that returns true in both cases.

Any help ?

Comment: But `x => i` **is** a member access. The member here being the captured variable on the capture context instance. Is the real question here perhaps "how to identify a capture context compiler generated type"?

Comment: 'The member here being the captured variable on the capture context instance' I don't understand this :(

Comment: @MarcGravell, based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressiontype?view=netframework-4.8 I would say the answer would be `Parameter` but I think the OP is looking for the inverse of that so essentially he would have to filter for `!=Parameter && !=MemberAccess`

Comment: @Jay, I am looking to tell if the expression passed is a memeber selection (x => x.member)  from it's first generic parameter (TSrc)

Comment: Then perhaps `Parameter` is what your looking for? I am not sure honestly as I don't usually use capturing lambdas I usually would use a static function... the thing about captures is that the capture becomes a field on the lambda so it's a tricky one especially without the use of reflection on the anonymous class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Captured lambda variables are stored in a generated struct type, passed in as a static constant. Your expression argument `x => i` is roughly equivalent to;

```cs
    public struct locals
    {
        public int i;
    }
    var localState = new locals { i = i };
    Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, int>>(
        Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
            Expression.Constant(localState, typeof(locals)),
            typeof(locals).GetField(nameof(locals.i))
        ),
        Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee),"x")
    );
```

As you can see, this also includes a member expression. What you want to prove, is that the member expression is based on the type of the expression parameter.

```cs
bool F<TSrc, TVal>(TSrc src, Expression<Func<TSrc, TVal>> exp) {
    var isMememberAccess = exp.Body is MemberExpression member
       && member.Expression is ParameterExpression parameter
       && parameter.Type == typeof(TSrc);
    ...
```

Comment: ok great thanks! this however returns a false negative for nested member access which I need, ie `F(organization, x => x => x.Sales.Manager.FirstName)` .. do I need to nest loop the expressions to get to the ParameterExpression for that ?

Comment: Right, something like `while(member.Expression is MemberExpression m) member = m;` But that probably wouldn't fit in a nice one liner.